# Cannot set google recaptcha v2 size to normal with mailpoet form

Tags: woocommerce, recaptcha

I have a mailpoet form and a Google recaptcha v2.
The default size I get is only the compact which means always square recaptcha.

How can I set the size to normal? with plugin? with php?

thank you